# jquery 'show' seems to get reverted when content loads

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery 'show' method that I'm using on a webpage to show a large amount of hidden data in a div when a button is clicked, something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#show").click(function(){
    $("div.show").show();    
    });
 });
```

I've used this before with no problems. What seems to happen in this case is that when I click the button the text shows, but page goes into a loading state. Then once its done the text disappears again. This seems to happen whether I use 'show' or 'toggle'. Has anyone come across this type of behaviour before? I'm not sure if it's an issue elsewhere in my code (I'm using php to generate the content for the div) or some problem with jquery.

[edit] here's the html for the button

```
<br/><button id='toggle'>Show all</button>
<div>All the content goes here</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the button and its surroundings? I suspect it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the button is a `submit` button (note that [`submit` is the **default type** of a `button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type), so if you don't have `type=`, it's a submit button). You need to prevent the default action (which is to submit the form). Note, though, that preventing the default on the button itself may not be sufficient cross-browser, you may need to use a `submit` handler on the form and cancel things there.

Similarly if the "button" is actually a link styled to look like a button, you'll need to prevent the default (which is to follow the link).

In a jQuery event handler, you can prevent the default by accepting the `event` argument that's passed to you and calling its `preventDefault` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#show").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div.show").show();    
    });
});
```

...or by doing `return false` from the handler, which will both prevent the default *and* stop propagation (bubbling).

Comment: No I'm using an actual button tag. I just did some testing, and there is a submit button on the page. I'm wondering if when I click the 'show' button, somehow the submit button is getting run again as well. Just a thought.

Comment: @whiterainbow: Your code is looking for a `button` with the ID `show`; your markup shows a `button` with the ID `toggle`.

Comment: sorry that's just me mixing up my metacode. The actual code is correct.

Comment: @whiterainbow: I'd be interested to know if `return false` solves the problem, even though it's just a `button`. It sounds like the button might be inside some link (inadvertently, I assume), and so the click bubbles to the link.

Comment: @whiterainbow: Note that `submit` is the default type of `button`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type So as you're not specifying a `type`, the type is `submit`. So if that button is in a form, it's submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem here, just leaving it as an answer in case it helps anyone else. Some of the other code I had was preventing the end `</form>` tag from displaying, which meant that the page was being interpreted as if the `<button>` belonged to the form. I think the browser treated it like a new submit button as TJ suggested, even though it wasn't coded as such, and resubmitted the form because of that.

Comment: LOL, I was just editing my answer: The `button` *was* coded as a submit button -- because that's the default value for `type` on `button` if you don't supply it.